# How do I properly consume and present cloud function server data via Ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to consume a json response from an Express style server in Firebase's Cloud functions, but I'm unable to present the response in the DOM. The response path and status (200) are good, but the response data I'm getting in the browser is my entire index.HTML page, not the json data.

Here's my basic set up in the cloud functions:

```
app.get("/tester", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ serverData: "Hello" });
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

and my React FE code to consume it:

```
function App() {
  let I;
  const onClick = () => {
    axios.get("/tester").then(res => {
      I = res.data.serverData;
      console.log(I);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>click</button>
      <div>{I}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Like I said above, the response data I'm getting in the dev tools is just the barebones index.html page, not the text I want to receive. How can I map this data to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You need `I` to be defined as a 'state' property within your function. Easiest way to do that is use React's useState hook. First add this to your script by including:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Then declare `I` using the useState hook and, after retrieving the data, use the associated setter to set the new value:

```
function App() {
  let [I, setI] = useState('');
  const onClick = () => {
    axios.get("/tester").then(res => {
      setI(res.data.serverData);
      console.log(I);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>click</button>
      <div>{I}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```